# Github Enterprise webhook integration not appearing in status

Tags: github, webhooks, status

I have integrated our Github Enterprise repository with an **internal tool** via a Webhook. The connection triggers the job on the internal tool correctly. I am now attempting to set the status check on the branch protection rule so that if the job passes or fails it can block a pull request from being merged.

However when I search for the available statuses there are none corresponding to our internal tool.

[image: Pull request status check]

[image: Branch protection status]

I'm not even sure what to type into Google to search for how to debug this, what is required, and if I need to go back to the internal tooling team and state that they need to expose an additional API.